# Accessing SQL Server Compact from SSMS 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, sql-server-ce-3.5

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 with SSMS, and I want to connect to SQL Server Compact (sdf files) but the option is disabled (greyed out).

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I also installed SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP 2 and their tools, see the first 2 items, but it stays greyed out:

[image]

Who knows a solution?

Comment: Not everybody here likes SHOUTING....

Comment: I am sorry. I edited te question. I didn’t want to be a inpolite

Comment: Thanks, appreciated :-)

Comment: Thanks, could you help me to resolve the issue? please. I will really appreciated!

Comment: No experience with SQL Compact. You could try **[SSMS v2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)**, it's free, and it offers lots of new features & improvements. Worth a try IMHO